# MASL OAuth Supporting Multiple Authentication flows

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a client application that accesses my WebAPI (1) using [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-integrated-windows-authentication?tabs=dotnet) and the [Authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#authorization-code) [Authentication flow].

Now I need to have a second WebAPI (2) access the original WebAPI (1) as well using the [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials) [Authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) [Authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows).

My question is whether you can configure WebAPI (1) to permit EITHER flow and where to do it or whether I would have to build a whole separate API to handle the Authorization code flow? I believe it would be in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs but I'm not certain how adding a a Client Credentials filter policy would be handled by the controller's filters.

```
  services.AddControllers(options => {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")
            .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    //Add Authorization code filter here as well??
   });
```

Comment: I believe this is similar to [Configuring multiple authentication schemes using Microsoft Identity](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38714) and I would have to write a custom AuthenticationHandler to accommodate multiple schemes as in [this sample](https://seangrimes.dev/post/multiple_auth_handlers_in_aspnetcore/). Seeking confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the StartUp of WebAPI (1), [RequireAuthenticationUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireauthenticateduser?view=aspnetcore-6.0) adds [DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.infrastructure.denyanonymousauthorizationrequirement?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to the current instance which enforces that the current **user** is authenticated. This is, obviously, not going to work for the service-to-service authorization I am looking to implement so needed to be removed to permit both the [Authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#authorization-code) AND ACL-based,  [Client Credentials Authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials).

Also, to get WebAPI (1) to permit the ACL-based authenticated token of WebAPI (2), I needed to add the following to the configuration of WebAPI (1):

```
{
    "AzureAD"
    { 
        // other properties
        "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL" : true,
        // other properties
    }
}
```

The resulting configuration policy ended up looking like:

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                   .RequireClaim("appid")
                    .Build();
```

Hoping someone stumbling on this finds this and it saves them time.